# How to link libc.a, into shared library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a shared library named nvdebug.so which is result of the compile.

I wanna have .so file linked with libc.a

although I searched almost all google site, I cannot find the solution.

I thought '--whole-archive' command is fittest way to solve.

If it works well, nvdebug.so file size must increase, but it doesn't work well.

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,nvdebug.so -o nvdebug.so -Wl,--whole-archive -L/usr/lib -lc -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

I don't know what I shoud modify, machanism of --whole-archive, and -shared command.

I'm really appreciate if you guys help me what to do

Comment: The question is... what's wrong with linking against `libc.so`?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot link a static library into a shared library, because shared libraries must contain position-independent code, and static libraries contain position-dependent code (called "relocatable code").  You will get a linker error at best.  So, this is impossible and the only option is to give up and try something else.

### Note

It is actually possible to compile a static library with position-independent code, which would allow you to do this, but this means recompiling `libc.a` which I'm assuming is a non-option.  Just add `-fPIC` to the `CFLAGS` when compiling libc, I think.